# Termwise product of a convergent series

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence of positive numbers for which the corresponding series is convergent. How can I show that there exists a sequence $(y_{n})_{n}$ converging to infinity such that the corresponding series of $(x_{n}y_{n})_{n}$ is convergent?

I am only interested in the existence of such sequence, but an explicit example is welcome :)

Comment: Here is an example: Choose a strictly increasing $(N_k)$ such that $\sum_{n=N_k}^{\infty} x_n < 1/3^k$ and set $y_n = 2^k$ if $N_k \leq n < N_{k+1}$.